# Fetching an Entity and passing it as parameter to the Service causes an issue with navigation property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I'm doing this in my Controller:

```
public ActionResult EditOrder(OrderViewModel viewModel)
{
    var order = _orderService.GetOrderById(viewModel.Id);

    order.OrderStatus = viewModel.OrderStatus;

    _orderService.UpdateOrder(order);

    Return View(viewModel);
}
```

... and UpdateOrder() is a method in my OrderService that does the following:

```
public bool UpdateOrder(EcommerceOrder order)
{
    var dbOrder = _dbContext.EcommerceOrders.Find(order.Id);

    dbOrder.OrderStatus = _dbContext.EcommerceOrderStatuses.Find(order.OrderStatus.Id);

    _dbContext.SaveChanges();

    return true;
}
```

Inexplicably (for me, at least), this causes Entity Framework to create a new OrderStatus rather than simply setting the existing one.

However, it works well if I change my Controller like this:

```
public ActionResult EditOrder(OrderViewModel viewModel)
{
    var order = new EcommerceOrder();

    order.OrderStatus = viewModel.OrderStatus;

    _orderService.UpdateOrder(order);

    Return View(viewModel);
}
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score -1):

Because the entity you are saving is new, EF will assume the child objects are new as well.

Try putting:

```
_dbContext.Entry(order.orderStatus).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Before the save changes call.

Comment: This doesn't work. The entity I'm trying to save is not new. I'm fetching the Entity from the Context: var dbOrder = _dbContext.EcommerceOrders.Find(order.Id).